# "Patch seems outdated" message received although the patch was created now

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created the following patch from the trunk:

```
Index: Index.aspx
===================================================================
--- Index.aspx  (revision 1421)
+++ Index.aspx  (working copy)
@@ -164,14 +164,13 @@
             var fetchXml = "<fetch mapping='logical'>\
                                <entity name='task'>\
                                    <attribute name='subject' width='250'/>\
+                                   <attribute name='statecode' width='100'/>\
+                                   <attribute name='wbs_statusreasonforcctask' width='100'/>\
                                    <attribute name='scheduledend' width='100'/>\
                                    <attribute name='actualend' width='100'/>\
                                    <attribute name='description' width='200'/>\
                                    <attribute name='ownerid' width='100'/>\
-                                   <attribute name='statecode' width='100'/>\
                                    <attribute name='createdon' width='100'/>\
-                                   <attribute name='wbs_statusreasonforcctask' width='100'/>\
-                                   <order attribute='statecode' descending='true'/>\
                                     <order attribute='actualend' descending='true'/>\
                                    <filter type='and'>\
                                        <condition attribute='regardingobjectid' operator='in'>\
```

and I am trying to apply it on the same file from a branch.
Here's how the same segment of the file looks like:

```
    var fetchXml = "<fetch mapping='logical'>\
                            <entity name='task'>\
                                <attribute name='subject' width='250'/>\
                                <attribute name='scheduledend' width='100'/>\
                                <attribute name='actualend' width='100'/>\
                                <attribute name='description' width='200'/>\
                                <attribute name='ownerid' width='100'/>\
                                <attribute name='statecode' width='100'/>\
                                <attribute name='createdon' width='100'/>\
                                <attribute name='wbs_statusreasonforcctask' width='100'/>\
                                <order attribute='statecode' descending='true'/>\
                            <order attribute='actualend' descending='true'/>\
                                <filter type='and'>\
                                            <condition attribute='regardingobjectid' operator='in'>\
```

When I apply the patch I get the following error message:
The patch seems outdated! The fileline and the patch line var fetchXml = "\ does not match.
However they are on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the tortoise merge tool didn't recognize the right filename.
I placed the patch at the root of the working copy and usually the tortoise merge tool can automatically detect the right file to patch. However since this file is called index.aspx and I have multiple of those it probably got confused and thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the problem. Since you're trying to apply it to a branch, I would recommend you to do a branch merge. In this way SVN should be able to manage all the intermediate changes.